# JDCBTemplate.exucute() call in long for loop iteration slows dramatically after a time

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am trying to fetch a list of article IDs with a GET Request. I returns a list including 10000 article IDs. Then I am trying to write a Postgresql database in a for loop which iterates the JSON array. The writing process is getting slower. I am sharing my method and code. Is there any idea or suggestion? Thanks.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("fetch")
public class DatabaseFetchController {

    ArticleFetchService articleFetchService;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @GetMapping()
    public String fetchArticles(){

        jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles_lookup(\n" +
                "article_id varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (article_id)\n)");

        var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(
                URI.create("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&RetMax=10000&term=brain&RetStart=1"))
                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = null;
        try {
            response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            String xmlResponse = response.body();
            JSONObject jsonResponse = XML.toJSONObject(xmlResponse);
            JSONObject jsonResponse1 = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("eSearchResult");
            int count = (int) jsonResponse1.get("Count");
            JSONArray jsonResponse2 = jsonResponse1.getJSONObject("IdList").getJSONArray("Id");

            for(int i = 0; i < jsonResponse2.length(); i++){

                jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT INTO articles_lookup(article_id) VALUES ('" + jsonResponse2.get(i) + "')  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING");
                Thread.sleep(200); // TODO: Will be deleted
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: It works very fast while writing first 800 article id, then dramatically decrease the speed. Approximately write two articles in a minute

Answer (score 1):

1. **This is a security leak**. Please review [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use prepared statements instead; in jdbcTemplate, that means you use e.g. `jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO articles_lookup(article_id) VALUES (?)", jsonResponse2.get(i));
2. transactions are expensive; commit from time to time. Review the jdbcTemplate docs on how to do this. The fastest DB behaviour happens when you commit not too often but not too infrequently either; perhaps around 100 or so actions. If, for data integrity, it is wiser to commit more or less frequently than that, then you should probably do that, but as this question is specifically about speed: Fire up a counter and commit every 100 INSERTs or so.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my method with using prepared statements. It is working very faster when sending request as a batch instead of JdbcTemplate.execute() in each iteration. Thanks to @rzwitserloot for answer, it was very beneficial to make changes. Also, using prepared statements is better because of security concerns.

```
@Override
public int fetchArticleIDs(){

    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS articles_lookup(\n" +
            "article_id varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (article_id)\n)");

    var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    var request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(
            URI.create("https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi?db=pubmed&RetMax=50000&term=brain&RetStart=1"))
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> response = null;
    try {
        response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        String xmlResponse = response.body();
        JSONObject jsonResponse = XML.toJSONObject(xmlResponse);
        JSONObject jsonResponse1 = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("eSearchResult");

        //System.out.println("Total number of articles " + (int) jsonResponse1.get("Count")); //2065705
        JSONArray jsonResponse2 = jsonResponse1.getJSONObject("IdList").getJSONArray("Id");

        String query = "INSERT INTO articles_lookup(article_id) VALUES(?) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING";
        Connection connection = Objects.requireNonNull(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse2.length(); i++) {
            preparedStatement.setString(1,jsonResponse2.get(i).toString());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
        return 0;

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | JSONException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 99;
    }
}
```